# Filter on array of objects directly in HTML via expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS website. I cannot modify the controller, because it's automatically generated from a .NET framework. That means that all my Angular stuff has to happen directly in the HTML. Now to the problem:

Depending on what is selected in a dropdown, I need to display additional data from that object. I've tried to use the pipe filter, but it doesn't work in the `{{ }}` expression.

```
//how my x.Images is defined on the controller - not the actual code
x.Images = [{
  Name: "Funny cat",
  Url: "cat.jpg"
}];

<select ng-options="image.Name as image.Name for image in x.Images" ng-model="x.SelectedImage"></select>
```

This gives me a dropdown:

```
//bare HTML no Angular
<select>
  <option value="Funny cat">Funny cat</option>
</select>
```

Now, let's say I want to output the `Url` of the `image`:

```
//won't work because x.SelectedImage is the 'Funny cat' name
<p>Image url: {{ x.SelectedImage.Url }}</p>

//should work but it doesn't
<p>Image url: {{ x.Images.filter(item => item.Name == x.SelectedImage)[0].Url }}</p>

//should work but I guess filter in the {{ }} expression doesn't work?
<p>Image url: {{ x.Images | filter:{Name:x.SelectedImage} }}
```

What can I do here? It has to be done via HTML. I cannot edit the controller or add them as key/value pairs, so I can do this:

```
<p>Image url: {{ x.ImagesAsPair[x.SelectedImage] }}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: You might like this.  Controller filters > Template filters:  https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/use-controller-filters-to-prevent-digest-performance-issues

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. `ng-change` works in this case.

```
<select ng-options... ng-change="x.SelectedImageBackup = (x.Images | filter:{Name:x.SelectedItem}:true})"></select>
```

Works flawlessly